# On the definition of the compressibility`

Tags: ideal-gas

The compressibility factor for a real gas can be defined in two equivalent ways,

$$Z = \frac{V_{measured}}{V_{ideal}} \equiv \frac{p_mV_m}{nRT} $$

where the subscripts $m$ stand for measured quantities. However, I have never seen the following definition (which I believe is also equivalent to the above two):

$$\frac{p_mV_m}{nRT} = \frac{p_m}{\frac{nRT}{V_m}} = \frac{p_m}{p_{ideal}}$$

Why isn't this definition used? Am I wrong, and is this definition somehow different from the ones given at the top?

If I am right, why isn't this definition used? In my opinion, it is much simpler to use (pressure is more readily measured than volume), and it's perhaps more intuitive as well.

Answer (score 0):

Definitions and practical measurements are two different matters. $Z$ is in essence an empirical fudge factor to account for the fact the gases are never really ideal. Therefore the 'definition' of $Z$ is best stated as the ratio of factors in the ideal gas equation. But for practical purposes it's easier to just compare the measured and predicted pressures of the compressed gas.

Comment: So the $Z = \frac{p_m}{p_{ideal}}$ is correct?

Comment: Even though one might consider $Z$ a 'fudge' factor, there is theory that can predict what $Z$ needs to be when molecules get real close to one another. When they are not so close $Z$ is 1. The ratio of measured vs. ideal should be close to what that theory predicts.